# How to display a video in a web page with audio and video filters?

Tags: php, javascript, html, video-streaming

I used vlc web plugin to display video player. How to display a video in a web page with audio and video filter option. vlc web plugin does not have any video and audio filter option

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the HTML5 tag.example:

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" src="example.mp3"></audio>
```

and also play the video you can use the tag
     
more information you can read about HTML5 knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Writing if somebody comes across this question in the future: The question asks about video, the posted answer talks about audio, so that's why I'm posting:

It is mentioned in the docs that one can not use filters for video files in the VLC Web Plugin Embed.

What you *could* do is make the embed act like a "regular" element (you'll have to research a bit, but I think it's the `windowless` property) instead of a "plugin" and overlay it with CSS3 filters (like `-webkit-filter:contrast(50%)`).